# What does "faire intervenir" mean?

Tags: sens

In [the book](https://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/CoqArt/coqartF.pdf) I read, there is this sentence

> Pour illustrer notre propos, prenons la démonstration d’un théorème artificiel faisant intervenir plusieurs occurrences de la même variable `m1`.

The [official English translation](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540208549) is:

> To illustrate these approaches, let us consider an artificial theorem that
>   contains several occurrences of a variable `m1`.

What I do not understand is the role of "faisant intervenir" in the original sentence. In isolation, "faisant" as well as "intervenir" have fairly straightforward meaning. However, as they appear in the original sentence, their utilization does not make sense to me.

I would like to ask for pointers/advice that can help me.

I was originally suspecting that "faire intervenir" might be an instance of "locution verbale", but I have failed to find it. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Faire intervenir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intervenir) means here:

> Tenir compte de, prendre en considération, faire jouer un rôle à.

so a closer literal (but heavier) translation would be:

> ...a theorem that let several occurences of the single m1 variable play a role.

Comment: Actually "involve" would work just fine IMO.

Comment: @Circeus Indeed. I just wanted to use an expression that exists in both languages.